# Way for delete all object inside an Collection "Mycoll" in blender 2.8

Tags: python

I find the bpy.ops, but not find the low level python way to get obj inside a collection and delete . Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unlink an object to remove it from a collection.**

Py console code, for example sake, creates a new collection that is a copy of "Collection 1".  It contains the default file objects "Cube" "Camera" and "Lamp", and like the original is a child of scene collection.

```
>>> mycol = D.collections['Collection 1'].copy()
>>> mycol.name
'Collection 1.002'

>>> mycol.objects[:]
[bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Lamp'], bpy.data.objects['Camera']]
```

To get by name and remove the "Cube" object from collection. (If there is no object named "Cube" in collection get returns `None`)

```
>>> cube = mycol.objects.get("Cube")
>>> # remove it from collection
>>> mycol.objects.unlink(cube)
>>> mycol.objects[:]
[bpy.data.objects['Lamp'], bpy.data.objects['Camera']]
```

Loop thru and empty the whole collection.  Note `mycol.objects` is boolean False when emtpy.

```
>>> while mycol.objects:
...     mycol.objects.unlink(mycol.objects[0])
...     
>>> mycol.objects[:]
[]
```

To remove the object `ob`  from file use `bpy.data.objects.remove(ob, do_unlink=True)`  Unlinking `do_unlink=True`is the default, and hence can be left out, will unlink from the collection, and all others containing this object, for you.

Comment: Nice explanation, in my case I solved with : while mycol.objects:
...     mycol.objects.unlink(mycol.objects[0])